# how to create a scrollable horizontal navigation menu but display when the user window scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

I want to create a navigation menu that must be scroll horizontally. But this navigation should be display when the user scroll down the window in the browser (Mobile+Desktop).

I have tried out this code so that the navigation menu display after scroll bottom but its item does not scroll horizontally. When removing position: fixed then it's item scroll horizontally.

So I want both functionalities scrollable navigation horizontal+display navigation menu bar when the user scrolls down the window.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 150 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 150) {
    document.getElementById("navigation").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navigation").style.top = "-150px";
  }
}
```

```css
#navigation {
  top: -50px;
  position: fixed;
}

.nav-header {
  background: #002347;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.nav-header a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.nav-header nav {
  width: 100%;
}

.itemlist {
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

.itemlist:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid #ece4e4;
}

.itemlist {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.itemlist,
.center {
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.scrolltab {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}

.scrolltab::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation" class="nav-header">
  <nav class="center scrolltab">
    <span class="itemlist"> About us </span>
    <span class="itemlist">Web Solution</span>
    <span class="itemlist">Web Application</span>
    <span class="itemlist">Scripting Language</span>
    <span class="itemlist">Andriod Application</span>
    <span class="itemlist">Contact</span>
  </nav>
</div>

<div style="padding:15px 15px 2500px;font-size:30px">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor dummy text sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
    irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: do you mean that you want the menu to take the whole window width horizontally AND only appear after a specific scrollpoint? I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "nav menu that scrolls horizontally" ? I don't see how we could scroll it, it only has five items at the moment. Horizontal scroll is the same as vertical scroll but in the X-axis. Or do you have an example webpage to show me?

Comment: Hey @LaurentC, Yes I mean the menu items should scroll in the X-Axis when the width is more than the browser window.

Comment: And the whole navigation menu should display after a scrollpoint in this case i.e. 150.

Answer (score 0):

To make the navigation bar scroll horizontally you need to give the containing element a width. i.e. add

```
#navigation {
  width:100%;
}
```

also, you have

```
.scrolltab::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

I am not sure whether you needed this for some reason, but on Microsoft Edge and Chrome at least it causes the scroll bar not to appear. Removing it renders the menu scrollable.